# scrollTop() in FullPage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, iscroll

I am using FullPage.js to create a one page website and because in mobile the content is not fitting I am using `scrollOverflow: true;`What I am trying to do is when I scroll down in section and going to the next section I want the previews section to get reseted to the top of it own section. What I realised is that is using iScroll so it actually doesn't scroll it just changing the position with `transfrom: translate(x, y)` I have tried to change the position to 0 when I am going to the next section but it sill records the last point

This is what I am doing

```
$('div.iScrollIndicator').css('transform','translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px)');
$('div.fp-scroller').css('transform','translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px)');
```

So after that If I am going back to the previews section it shows me the top of my section and the slide bar as well but if I scroll inside I can only scroll to top so it will start scrolling from bottom where was my last position.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would use the [iScroll functions](http://iscrolljs.com/) to do so. If you really need feel free to [contact me](http://alvarotrigo.com/#contact) for it.